# Dimension - Content is being truncated

Tags: java, json, swing

So i have this existing method on our project which defines the width and height of a widget using `Dimension()`:

```
wProps.setBounds("Widget.frame.bounds", new Rectangle(WidgetStartPosition.getInstance().getStartPos(),new Dimension(getDefWidth(), getDefHeight())))
```

But `getDefWidth()` and `getDefHeight()` both retrieves hard coded values.

> example: int height = 360; int width = 210;

```
public void setBounds(String key, Rectangle r)
{
    if (key == null || "".equals(key) || r == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        jObject.put(X, r.x);
        jObject.put(Y, r.y);
        jObject.put(WIDTH, r.width);
        jObject.put(HEIGHT, r.height);
        getLocalJSONObject().put(key, jObject);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

because i noticed if the width and height for new `Dimension()` are both hard coded. Then if the width of content of the widget is more than the width defined in the new `Dimension()`, the content would be truncated and cut.
What i want to do is to set values in `Dimension()` depending on the total width and total height of whatever the content will be of the widget since the content of the widget changes every day. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode width/height values of any Swing component. Each component is responsible for determining its own size and then a layout manager can do its job when determining the size/location of each component on a panel.

> What i want to do is to set values in Dimension() depending on the total width and total height of whatever the content will be of the widget

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your component. This is a dynamic calculation that can be done whenever a property of your component changes.

So as the content changes the preferred size can also change. Think of a component like a JLabel. As the text changes its preferred size changes.